# laravel 5.2 adding orWhere clause using loop returns an error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel-5

I have this code that will create multiple orWhere clauses for my query builder as I cannot do this in one line as I am passing an array variable:

```
$img_Search = DB::table('attachment')
                foreach($img_arr as $searchie)
                    ->orWhere('url', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchie.'%')
                }
                ->get();
```

The problem here is that it returns an error if there is a loop in between the query builder, though I found the same code posted here in stack and it was marked as accepted. This is really bothering me as to why a simple loop is not permitted in between.

Answer (score 1):

That's invalid syntax in PHP, what you can do though is add a few more characters to that and it should work.

```
$query= DB::table('attachment');
foreach($img_arr as $searchie)
    $query->orWhere('url', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchie.'%');
}
$img_Search= $query->get();
```